# How do I put the individual values of the Deaths in the States into the Data frame

Tags: python, loops

So I created a Data frame with the the column name States

```
States = ('California','Utah','Texas','New York','Ohio','Mississippi')

Deaths = pd.DataFrame({'States' : States})
```

The Data frame is fine. However, when I create a for loop to grab some information from another data frame (df) and apply the sum function in a for loop it only takes does it for the last variable in the States section.

```
for x in States:
    Deaths['Total Deaths'] = df[df['state'] == x]['n_killed'].sum()
```

Comment: so you want to add information to the dataframe or extract from it? because the title contradicts the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explaination about why your code did not work: notice that `df[df['state'] == x]['n_killed'].sum()` is a single float. So when you try to assign a single float value to a column `Deaths['Total Deaths']`, it will add a list with the same float number to that column. Because you are implementing it in a for loop, only the last `state` will be assigned due to refreshment.

A simple fix can be:

```
for x in States:
    Deaths.loc[x,'Total Deaths'] = df[df['state'] == x]['n_killed'].sum()
```

Alternatively if you want to use `groupby`, you may want to first select those States that you are interested:

```
df = df[df['state'].isin(States)]
```

And sum over `'n_killed'` grouped by 'state'

```
df1=df.groupby('state').agg({'n_killed':'sum'})
```

And then merged it with your dataframe `Deaths`

```
Deaths=Deaths.merge(df1,left_on='States',right_on=df1.index)
```

Because I do not have access to your data, it is impossible to check the correctness. Please modify the codes if needed.